# How to pass an object ID from a button click in asp .net core 3

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to pass an object ID from a cardView.  item.vehicleID value should be passed to the create method of a controller. When I click the button it should also route me to following page "https://localhost:44367/User/Bookings/Create".

I have my code like this,

```
<div class="card-columns">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <img class="lazyload" src="@("~/VehicleImages/"+item.vehicleImageName)" asp-append-version="true" width="100%" height="100%" />
                <h5 class="card-title">@item.vehicleType</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Vehicle Availability: @item.vehicleAvailability</p>
                <p class="card-text">Plate Number: @item.plateNumber</p>
                <p class="card-text">Price/Day: @item.vehiclePricePerDay</p>
                <p class="card-text">Transmission: @item.transmission</p>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control" value="Book" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Areas=User", "Create", "BookingsController", new { id = item.vehicleID })'" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

What I actually want is, when I click the **input button**, I want to get the item.vehicleID and pass the ID value to the Create method in the BookingsController that I'm calling which is located in the **User** Folder and this User Folder is located in the **Areas** Folder.

The below code lines shows how I tried,

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control" value="Book" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Areas=User", "Create", "BookingsController", new { id = item.vehicleID })'" />
```

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control" value="Book" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "BookingsController", "User",  new { id = item.vehicleID })'" />
```

```
<input type="submit" asp-controller="Bookings" asp-area="User" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-info form-control" value="Book" itemid="vehicleID" />
```

Currently I tried the above code lines but it doesn't load the page or anything. So what I actually want is to direct to this link "https://localhost:44367/User/Bookings/Create" when I click the button and it also should pass the vehicleID from item.vehicleID to the Create method of the BookingsController from that button click.

Comment: onclick? You are trying to call javascript code (client side) with that.

Comment: Also the last one should have worked if your parameter is named _itemId_ Could you start the developer tools on your browser and check the console output to see what is the answer returned by your server?

Comment: Can you add full html?, because atleast one of the code should have worked unless if the submit button is not inside a form.

Comment: You are using input type=submit which you would normally use to submit the form that that button is in.
I would try a changing it to a anchor tag, rather than input type submit, can we see the controller action that is supposed to receive these requests.

Comment: input type=submit is for posting forms, if you just want a link to a controller action that is a GET request then something like:   <a asp-area="User" asp-controller="Bookings" asp-action="Create" asp-route-itemid="@item.vehicleId" >Book</a>